# How to refresh a page with javascript and set request header?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Problem:

I need to send a request from javascript to the server, containing a set header, that will reload the entire browser window on response.

jQuery ajax it seems does not fully load the browser window and can only re-target the document.

Essentially I'd like to do a window.location.reload(true) whilst also setting a request header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify custom HTTP headers other then when using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Can you have the browser reload the entire window on response though?

Comment: No, you can't. You can replace pretty much the entire DOM, but you're still working with the same environment.